# Why do I not get the response as RAW API RESPONSE specified by Dialogflow?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, api-ai

I asked this question before, came to a wrong conclusion because Dialogflow V1 client library gives response in the [format specified by Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/docs/simulator) and Dialogflow V2 client did not so I thought the [response format has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275144/how-to-make-request-query-to-dialogflow-using-v2-api). I used

```
response.query_result.parameters.fields
```

to access the parameters sent by the Dialogflow in an object format and not a JSON string. Where did I go wrong or is the response format correct and Google did not update the Dialogflow documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have anything set up right now in nodeJS to test this, but translating from my python requests I think that it should be

```
request.body.queryResult.parameters['fields']
```

idk if this could also be helpful to you but in python my code looks like this

```
req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
auth_code = req.get('queryResult').get('parameters').get('number')
```

Comment: I found solution for this long time ago and forgot to post it.
There is a python package called protobuf. We can use 
MessagetoDict(response.query_result.parameters) to directly convert the object to dictionary and access the values using keys. I don't if your code works, I'll test it and post the results.